# How do I push second view controller from a class that is accessed by first view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have programatically initialised the first view controller to display a calendar. I used the code in the gitHub file below for displaying the calendar:
https://github.com/Akhilendra/calenderAppiOS

I made a few changes to the code to remove the change colour functionality and replaced the navigation bar button "Theme" with a button labelled "History".
I also created a navigationController and ViewController on the Main.storyboard. I have also linked the ViewController storyBoard object to the ViewController class. 
In the project in the link, when you click a date, that particular cell changes colour. But in my project on clicking a date, I wish to send the user to the next screen where the date will be displayed (among other functions that I wish to do).

The didSelectItem() function of the calendar is located in a class called CalendarView. The problem here is that I cannot access navigationController.pushViewController() in this class since navigationController is an object of UIViewController class.

I have tried creating an instance of the firstViewController class and used pushViewController on this instance but this hasn't worked.
The project works fine and the calendar is displayed and the cells work on being selected. The only problem is that the next screen does not appear.

//View controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Title for the view:
    self.title = "My Calendar"
    //Month-year will be displayed if this property is set to false:
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent=false
    //Bg colour of the entire view:
    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.white

    //Add the subview that contains the calendar:
    view.addSubview(calendarView)
    //Constraints for the calendar:
    calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
    calendarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive=true
    calendarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive=true
    calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 365).isActive=true

    //The left bar button on navigation controller:
    let leftBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "History", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(leftBarBtnAction))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarBtn
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    calendarView.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

//Defines what happens when left bar button is clicked:
@objc func leftBarBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    print("History")

}

//Object of type CalendarView:

let calendarView: CalendarView = {
    let v=CalendarView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return v
}() 

}
```

//CalendarView class:

```
class CalendarView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MonthViewDelegate {

var numOfDaysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
var currentMonthIndex: Int = 0
var currentYear: Int = 0
var presentMonthIndex = 0
var presentYear = 0
var todaysDate = 0
var firstWeekDayOfMonth = 0   //(Sunday-Saturday 1-7)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    initializeView()
}



func changeTheme() {
    myCollectionView.reloadData()

    monthView.lblName.textColor = UIColor.blue
    //Colour of the button for the next month:
    monthView.btnRight.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    //Colour of the button for the previous month:
    monthView.btnLeft.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

    for i in 0..<7 {
        (weekdaysView.myStackView.subviews[i] as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}

func initializeView() {
    currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
    currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    todaysDate = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    //for leap years, make february month of 29 days
    if currentMonthIndex == 2 && currentYear % 4 == 0 {
        numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] = 29
    }
    //end

    presentMonthIndex=currentMonthIndex
    presentYear=currentYear

    setupViews()

    myCollectionView.delegate=self
    myCollectionView.dataSource=self
    myCollectionView.register(dateCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] + firstWeekDayOfMonth - 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! dateCVCell
    //cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
        cell.isHidden=true
    } else {
        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
        cell.isHidden=false
        cell.lbl.text="\(calcDate)"
        if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
            //Disable user interaction on past dates
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
            //Colour of the text in past date cells
            cell.lbl.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        } else {
            //Enable user interaction on upcoming dates
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            //Colour of the text in upcoming date cells
            cell.lbl.textColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell=collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    //Print the selected date:
    let lbl = cell?.subviews[1] as! UILabel

    print(lbl.text!)


}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width/7 - 8
    let height: CGFloat = 40
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}

func getFirstWeekDay() -> Int {
    let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!
    //return day == 7 ? 1 : day
    return day
}

func didChangeMonth(monthIndex: Int, year: Int) {
    currentMonthIndex=monthIndex+1
    currentYear = year

    //for leap year, make february month of 29 days
    if monthIndex == 1 {
        if currentYear % 4 == 0 {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 29
        } else {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 28
        }
    }
    //end

    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    myCollectionView.reloadData()

    monthView.btnLeft.isEnabled = !(currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex && currentYear == presentYear)
}

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(monthView)
    monthView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive=true
    monthView.delegate=self

    addSubview(weekdaysView)
    weekdaysView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: monthView.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive=true

    addSubview(myCollectionView)
    myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weekdaysView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive=true
}

let monthView: MonthView = {
    let v=MonthView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return v
}()

let weekdaysView: WeekdaysView = {
    let v=WeekdaysView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return v
}()

let myCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    let myCollectionView=UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=false
    return myCollectionView
}()

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

class dateCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    layer.cornerRadius=5
    layer.masksToBounds=true

    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(lbl)
    lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    lbl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    lbl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    lbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive=true
}

let lbl: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "00"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return label
}()

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

//get first day of the month
extension Date {
var weekday: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
}
var firstDayOfTheMonth: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from:  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: self))!
}
}

//get date from string
extension String {
 static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()

var date: Date? {
    return String.dateFormatter.date(from: self)
}
}
```

//MonthView class:

```
// The protocol with didChangeMonth function:
protocol MonthViewDelegate: class {
func didChangeMonth(monthIndex: Int, year: Int)
}

class MonthView: UIView {
//The array that contains the name of the months:
var monthsArr = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
 //Index of the current month:
 var currentMonthIndex = 0
 //Index of the current year:
 var currentYear: Int = 0

//Define an object of the protocol MonthViewDelegate:
var delegate: MonthViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear

    //Index of the current month:
    currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) - 1
    //Index of the current year:
    currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())

    setupViews()

    //Disable the previous month button on launch:
    btnLeft.isEnabled=false
}

//Change the number of days in a month(next/previous):
 @objc func btnLeftRightAction(sender: UIButton) {
    //When next month button is clicked:
    if sender == btnRight {
        //Increment the index of the current month:
        currentMonthIndex += 1
        //Check if next month is January of the next year:
        if currentMonthIndex > 11 {
            //Reset the current month index:
            currentMonthIndex = 0
            //Increment the current year:
            currentYear += 1
        }
    }
        //When previous month button is clicked:
    else {
        //Decrement the index of the current month:
        currentMonthIndex -= 1
        //Check if previous month is December of the last year:
        if currentMonthIndex < 0 {
            //Reset the current month index:
            currentMonthIndex = 11
            //Decrement the current year:
            currentYear -= 1
        }
    }
    // Set label text for Month-Year:
    lblName.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"
    //Call didChangeMonth on delegate object:
    delegate?.didChangeMonth(monthIndex: currentMonthIndex, year: currentYear)
}

func setupViews() {
    //Add label 'Month-Year'
    self.addSubview(lblName)
    //Constraints for label Month-Year:
    lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    lblName.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    lblName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive=true
    lblName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive=true

    //Set label text for Month-Year:
    lblName.text="\(monthsArr[currentMonthIndex]) \(currentYear)"

    //Add view for 'next month' button:
    self.addSubview(btnRight)
    //Constraints for 'next month' button:
    btnRight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    btnRight.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    btnRight.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
    btnRight.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive=true

    //Add view for 'previous month' button:
    self.addSubview(btnLeft)
    btnLeft.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    btnLeft.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    btnLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
    btnLeft.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive=true
}

//The label that displays Month-year
let lblName: UILabel = {
    let lbl=UILabel()
    //Default text for month and year:
    lbl.text="Default Month Year text"
    //Colour of month and year:
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.blue
    //Alignment of month and year:
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    //Font size and style of month and year:
    lbl.font=UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return lbl
}()

//Button for next month:
let btnRight: UIButton = {
    let btn=UIButton()
    //Title for next month button:
    btn.setTitle(">", for: .normal)
    //Title colour of next month button:
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    //Function on next month button click:
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnLeftRightAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

//Button for previous month:
let btnLeft: UIButton = {
    let btn=UIButton()
    //Title for previous month button:
    btn.setTitle("<", for: .normal)
    //Title colour for previous month button when enabled:
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    //Function on previous month button click:
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnLeftRightAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    //Title colour of the previous button when disabled:
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .disabled)
    return btn
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

//WeekdaysView class:

```
class WeekdaysView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear

    setupViews()
}

 func setupViews() {
    addSubview(myStackView)
    myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    myStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    myStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    myStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive=true

    //Array that contains name of the days in a week:
    var daysArr = ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
    //Iteration for the properties of each day in a week:
    for i in 0..<7 {
        let lbl=UILabel()
        //Text in the label for weekdays:
        lbl.text=daysArr[i]
        //Alignment of the text in week day label:
        lbl.textAlignment = .center
        //Colour of the label for weekdays:
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.blue
        //Stack that contains all labels with weekday names:
        myStackView.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
    }
}

//The stack that will contain the names of the days in a week:
let myStackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView=UIStackView()
    //Distribute the labels as:
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return stackView
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that, in `CalendarView` class, where you have `print(lbl.text!)` inside the `didSelectItemAt` function, you want to Push to a new view controller (presumably passing the selected date)?

Comment: @DonMag , yes. I want to push the new screen from this class.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a delegate protocol. For example: `HandleDateTransfer`.

1. Define a protocol with the function. e.g. `setDate()`.
2. Add a weak delegate property to the `CalendarView` class.

   weak var dateTransferdelegate: HandleDateTransfer?
3. Attach the delegate to the `CalendarView` class.
4. Conform to the protocol and implement the `setDate()` method in the function where you want to set the date.
5. Call the `setDate()` method inside `didSelectItemAt` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same delegate / protocol pattern you're using for your `didChangeMonth` functionality.

Essentially, create a new protocol:

```
// The protocol with didSelectDate function:
protocol SelectDateDelegate: class {
    func didSelectDate(dayIndex: Int, monthIndex: Int, year: Int)
}
```

Have your ViewController conform to that protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SelectDateDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         // as normal ...

         view.addSubview(calendarView)

         // set the new delegate
         calendarView.delegate = self

    }

    func didSelectDate(dayIndex: Int, monthIndex: Int, year: Int) {
        let vc = DateDetailViewController()
        vc.dateData = dayIndex // or however you're managing the data
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Then in `CalendarView` class:

```
var delegate: SelectDateDelegate?
```

and in `didSelectItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell=collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    //Print the selected date:
    let lbl = cell?.subviews[1] as! UILabel

    print(lbl.text!)

    // whatever variables / properties you're using to track day / month / year
    delegate?.didSelectDate(dayIndex: dayVal, monthIndex: monthVal, year: yearVal)

}
```